# JavaScript Fill Rest of Page Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a page for our highschool mun team and have done no design yet, just trying to get the individual parts working.

What I am stuck on now is using JavaScript to make my content div fill the rest of the pages vertical height.

Here is my HTML, maybe I am just out of it, but it appears as though everything is labeled correctly and should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>NCHS MUN</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script>
function resize() 
{
document.getElementById("content").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - document.getElementById("top"));
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="resize()">
<div id="top">
<header><a href="index.html" class="title">NCHS Model UN</a></header>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is my CSS, again, everything should work.

```
HTML, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
font-family: arial;
background-color: #D0D0D0;
}

header {
display: block;
background-color: #0000FF;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
}

a.title {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2px;
font-size: 72px;
}

ul.nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}

ul.nav li {
display: inline;
float: left;
background-color: #FFA500;
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid black;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 5px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
}

#content {
display: block;
overflow: auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However, when the page does load, only the border of the "content" div appears. Why is it not expanding to the rest of the page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use JavaScript to manipulate the style like this.

The issue with your script however is that you've got `- document.getElementById("top")`.

You haven't specified it's the height of the `#top` element that needs to be deducted.

Comment: Eh. That did not work, it only made it 100% + the height of the top, not what it should be.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't realise you were trying to do it in JavaScript by taking away the `#top` height.

Comment: Its chill. Upvoting the question may help though ;D

Comment: Hmm. How would I do that then? Because I don't want to specify a height for the navigation or header so that they can re-size.

Comment: Your navigation and header are within your `#top` div. So the `#top` div will automatically adjust it's height to fit it's content. So the JavaScript in theory should remove the correct height value to fill the page. Currently you have a border on `#content` which may create a vertical scrollbar as the border is considered to be on the outside of the `#content` div.

Comment: It is not on the outsiding because of the border box property

Comment: Okay, be aware it's not fully cross-browser compatible on it's own: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ you need to use `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes too.